# Como printar uma função no Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estou tentendo fazer essa código funcionar mas não to conseguindo.

Entra o nome e o ano de nascimento, e retorna os valores corretos dps, mas não to conseguindo voltar o numero de anos... Qual é o meu erro?

```
print 'Digite seu nome:'
nome = raw_input()

print 'Digite o seu ano de nascimento:'
ano = raw_input()

def ano_covertido(idade):
    ano = raw_input()
    ano_covertido = int(ano)
    ano_atual = date.today().year
    ano_atual - ano

print 'Bem vindo %s' % (nome)
print 'Voce tem %s de idade' % (idade)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função `ano_covertido` não está sendo executada, e ela também não retorna nenhum resultado.

`ano_covertido` deve ser parecido com isto:

```
def ano_covertido(ano): 
    # Pega o ano do dia atual
    ano_atual = date.today().year 
    # Retorna a diferenca entre o ano atual e informado na funcao
    return ano_atual - ano
```

Para pegar a entrada do usuário, faça assim:

```
# Guarda em "nome" a entrada do usuario
nome = raw_input('Digite seu nome:')
# Guarda um inteiro em "ano"
ano = int(raw_input('Digite o seu ano de nascimento: '))
```

Agora que você sabe o ano, chame a função:

```
idade = ano_covertido(ano)
```

Finalmente, mostre as informações ao usuário:

```
print ('Bem vindo %s' % (nome))
print ('Voce tem %s de idade' % (idade))
```

O código completo fica assim:

```
from datetime import date

def ano_covertido(ano):
    ano_atual = date.today().year 
    return ano_atual - ano        

nome = raw_input('Digite seu nome:')

ano = int(raw_input('Digite o seu ano de nascimento: '))

idade = ano_covertido(ano)

print ('Bem vindo %s' % (nome))
print ('Voce tem %s de idade' % (idade))
```